# ajax MVc return to select a single div from return./

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have the below returning an entire page including the partial when it returns from server.

How can I just select a div within the return and disregard the rest?

```
 $('#btnNext').click(function () {
        var idVal = parseInt(document.getElementById('pagenumber').value) + 1;
        var newPriceVal = 1;
        $('#newPart').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../getMySubjectList',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            data: { catogoryId: newPriceVal, pageid: idVal },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'

        })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#newPart').html(result);
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            })
    });
```

Comment: So `result` contains the HTML for an entire document?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the results into a dom element, then read them out by div id.

```
var domElement = $('<returnedHtml>').append($.parseHTML(result));
var returnDiv = $('#divId', domElement);    
$('#newPart').html(returnDiv[0]);
```

Obviously change `#divId` to match your returned div.

Your full code would become:

```
$('#btnNext').click(function () {
        var idVal = parseInt(document.getElementById('pagenumber').value) + 1;
        var newPriceVal = 1;
        $('#newPart').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../getMySubjectList',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            data: { catogoryId: newPriceVal, pageid: idVal },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'

        })
            .success(function (result) {
                var domElement = $('<returnedHtml>').append($.parseHTML(result));
                var returnDiv = $('#divId', domElement);    
                $('#newPart').html(returnDiv[0]);
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            })
    });
```